# Can we efficiently modify the largest singular value of a matrix without computing the full SVD?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

Say we've got $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, and $A=U\textrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_N) V^\top$ is its [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). For a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$, I am curious if there is a method for efficiently evaluating

$$\hat{A}=U\textrm{diag}(f(\sigma_1),\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n)V^\top,$$
without having to compute the full SVD of $A$ (which can be quite expensive).

My motivation in thinking this might be possible is because for eigenvalues, one can compute the largest eigenvalue-eigenvector pair much faster (numerically speaking) than performing a full eigendecomposition. However, I feel like despite this, the answer is probably still no?

Comment: @littleO That's a good point -- both operations are quite similar, so if there was an efficient method for computing one, it may translate to the other. However, I haven't seen anything discussing a faster method of computing a rank-$k$ approximation either. I suppose I was hoping that perhaps this is a "simpler" operation, in some sense.

Comment: The answer given suggests a good method, so I'm going to delete my above comments.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7170/svd-and-lanczos-method You can use Krylov methods for the SVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried implementing this, but it is at least in theory possible to find the top singular vectors (left and right) by power method (just google "SVD power method" and such), and some others -- see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281269/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-leading-singular-value-of-a-very-large) to start and follow the links.

Of course, once you know the top singular vectors and the top singular value it solves the problem in your question.

Indeed, $A=UDV^T$ means precisely that $A=\sum_i \sigma_i u_iv_i^T$ ($A$ takes the unit vector $v_i$ to $\sigma_i u_i$). To replace $\sigma_1$ by $f(\sigma_1)$ just add $(f(\sigma_1)-\sigma_1 )u_1v_1^T$ to $A$.

Comment: Once you know the top singular vectors (left and right) and the top singular value, how do you get $\hat A$? I don't see it.

Comment: See the edit for this.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: Wait a minute, so from the resources I've found it looks like they apply power method to find an eigenvalue-eigenvector pair of $A^\top A=V\textrm{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_n^2)V^\top$. So how do we get *both* the right and left singular vectors?

Comment: For non-zero singular values, the left singular vectors are eigenvectors of $A^TA$, and the right singular vectors are eigenvectors  of $AA^T$.  Equivalently,  left singular vectors of $A$ are right singular vectors of $A^T$ and vice versa. Once you have any algorithm for one you just apply it to the transposed matrix (though the cost of running it might change of your matrix is very non-square).

Comment: @Max Oh I see, so the algorithm for computing $u_1$, $v_1$, and $\sigma_1$ would run power method twice?

Comment: Yes, as one option. But I think you can save some compute, after all $(A^TA)^n=A^T(AA^T)^{n-1}A$.

Comment: Right on, thanks for all the help @Max !